# How to use Google PubSub without Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-pubsub

How can I use Google PubSub to retrieve billing updates without using cloud functions? I am using the code below currently but it says that `onPublish` does not exist:

```
const { PubSub } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const pubsub = new PubSub('MyProjectID');



handleServerEvent = pubsub.topic(GOOGLE_PLAY_PUBSUB_BILLING_TOPIC)
  .onPublish(async (message) => {

  })
```

> TypeError: pubsub.topic(...).onPublish is not a function

I am using Node.js and want to react to events published on a topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`onPublish()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.pubsub.topicbuilder#pubsubtopicbuilderonpublish) method is a part of Cloud Functions API. You need to use [`createSubscription()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/latest) to get a [Subscription](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/pubsub/subscription) object and then use it to listen for new messages. Try the following:

```
const listenToTopic = async (topicName: string) => {
  const [sub] = await pubsub
    .topic(topicName)
    .createSubscription("subscriptionName");

  sub.on("message", (message) => {
    message.ack();
    console.log(`Received message: ${message}`);  
  });
};

// start listener
listenToTopic(GOOGLE_PLAY_PUBSUB_BILLING_TOPIC)
```

After creating the subscription once you need to change `createSubscription("subscriptionName")` to `subscription("subscriptionName")` to listen to incoming messages as the subscription has been created already

Comment: Where do I get the subscriptionName? I have created a topic via the Google Cloud which is called "play-billings" where google emits billing update events to this topic. There was no subscriptionName.

Comment: @SwiftiSwift you can create a subscription [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/subscription/list) and use the "Subscription ID". But the SDK will create one automatically when you run the `createSubscription`. The subscription name is up to you e.g. what is the service name where your code is running or so.

Comment: What's the benefit of Subscriptions? I was following a tutorial and they only listen to a topic without using subscriptions as in my code example in the question. I am wondering whether google will still emit event even if the subscriptionName will be something custom.

Comment: @SwiftiSwift a subscriber (with given name) will only listen to their topics (just like YouTube to explain it in easy way). It's just an identifier.